# Uncaught ReferenceError: postscribe is not defined at ctkvidinit ((index):3258)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am having this problem on my WordPress site. I would like to go into the file and add postscribe so that it can be used, however it is impossible to find the file where this source code is called.  I have downloaded the full website and done keyword searches on Atom, but nothing has come up. How can I find where this code is being rendered?

Part of this function:

```
 function ctkvidinit()
 {
   if(ctkloaded == 0)
   {   

  if(jQuery('#sharehid').length)
  {
    postscribe("#sharehid", "<script type='text/javascript' data-cfasync='false' src='//apps.shareaholic.com/assets/pub/"+"shareaholic"+".js' data-shr-siteid='xxxxxx' async='async' ><\/script>", { error: function(e){ console.log(e); } } );
  }
```

....

}

Please note also that I removed shareaholic from my website, yet for some reason this is still being called.

Comment: https://github.com/krux/postscribe is this referenced?

Comment: thank you! I checked and realized that the postscribe file that was being referenced was missing from my resources... i re-added postscribe and the errors disappeared! however I would still like to know where this is coming from.... is it adsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postscribe was missing from my resources so I added postscribe.min.js from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/postscribe/2.0.8/postscribe.min.js.

However I still do not know why postscribe was being referenced, my understanding was that it is to load ads asynchronously, however I did not find this ctkvidinit function in my plugins.